# python error (board = pyfirmata2.Arduino("COM5"))

Tags: python

i work with python with cv2 and media pip and pyfirmata2 but there is error

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyfirmata2
import math

board = pyfirmata2.Arduino("COM5")
lightPin = board.get_pin("d:3:p")
```

i try to change python version but it not work
in youtube no one help me

Comment: That's not an error. Or at least, it's an incomplete error: it doesn't say what the actual error is.

Comment: @9769953 i upload termenal error agian you can see it and help me if you can

Comment: What does the program print when you run it? Please copy-paste everything to your question, including the traceback.

Comment: @pts i try to enter all code but it doesnot work stack over flow say you cannot edit code

Comment: You can edit your own question on StackOverflow.com. Just click on *Edit*, and add more info to the text area, and then click *Save edits*.

Comment: @pts it say to me you cannot

Comment: Editing your own question should work, even for new users just like you. Maybe you are using a weird web browser or a browser extension, or your (new) user account in StackOverflow.com is somehow special.

Comment: Run the code; then copy-paste the full error traceback, and add that traceback to your question.